# Как при выполнении кода заставить крутиться загрузчик во вкладке браузера?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как обманывать браузер? У меня есть такой код, который обновляет содержимое. Как можно сделать так, чтобы при выполнении кода крутился бы загрузчик во вкладке  браузера, а после — остановился.

```
$('').load(url+'', function(data) {
    // Код
});
```

[image: Снимок экрана с обозревателем, в котором загружается главная страница Stack Overflow]

Comment: вставьте с помощью js тег img с ссылкой на какую-нибудь очень большую картинку, должно сработать

Comment: @RobertDampilon попробовал даже создать iframe но это не работает корректно и снижает скорость!

Comment: вот решение, есть даже пример, работает в хроме https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39269407/how-to-manually-show-tab-loading-indicator-via-javascript

Comment: Может почитать раздел "управление иконкой html-страницы" или что-то такое

Comment: @RobertDampilon обновил вопрос

Comment: @nick_n_a обновил вопрос

Comment: http://lab.ejci.net/favico.js/ - попробуй это
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837261/how-to-animate-a-favicon - или это (Этот вариант мне нравится больше для тебя), только нужно найти гифку

Comment: думаю, стоит дополнение оформить как ответ

Comment: @mymedia пожалуйста

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Этот текст взят из [правки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/701111/revisions#spacer-3d8cdbfa-d912-451d-85ad-8ec5c40d44e3) вопроса.*

По-моему нету другого решения. Моя реализация.

```
$('body').on('click', 'a[href]', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var url = this.href;
  var iframe = $('<iframe id="progress" src="' + url + '">').hide();
  $('body .page').append(iframe);
  $('.page').load(url + ' .page_parent', function(data) {
    // Ваш код
    $('iframe#progress').remove();
  });
});
```